# How to use sensor_msgs/Joy instead of joystick_drivers/Joy?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to migrate my joystick programs from deprecated joystick_drivers to sensor_msgs equivalent.

When I used joystick_drivers I run an executable joy_node..., then a node "joy_node" was created to publish the Joy msg (I just suscribe to it and was simple)...

but... with sensor_msgs equivalent, I don't know what executable do I have to run to see a publisher node giving me the Joy msgs... I have tried the following simple listener..., but I simply can't see anybody (with rostopic & rxgraph) publishing Joy msgs...

Thanks for your help!

---

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>

void myCallback (const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < msg->axes.size(); ++i) {
    ROS_INFO("Axis %d is now at position %f", i, msg->axes[i]);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("joy", 1000, myCallback);
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12181/how-to-use-sensor_msgs/joy-instead-of-joystick_drivers/joy?/) by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2011-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick#Starting_the_Joy_Node.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2011-12-01**:
Thanks for your help, I have realized that there is no way to avoid installing "joystick_drivers". Because, some sensor msgs has their own manipulation stacks (i.e. Joy needs "joystick_drivers" stack). The correct way is to install the missing stack; thanks a lot!          PS. The code is correct.